# How can I handle exception in a MVC web application (Servlet and Jsp)?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a MVC web application: a centralized servlet, few jsp and a DAO.
in my Servlet I have a switch statement as the sequent:

```
try {
            DAO d = new DAO();
            List<Entry> var = d.listentries();

            switch (enumPage.fromString(operation)) {
                case list:
                    request.setAttribute("list", var);
                    link = "listentries.jsp";
                    break;

                case home:
                    request.setAttribute("home", var);
                    link = "index.jsp";
                    break;

                case searchEntry:
                    request.setAttribute("searchEntry", var);
                    link = "searchentry.jsp";
                    break;

                 // [...]
            }

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(
                    NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            link = "Error.jsp";
        }
```

How can I handle exception in my program ?
Do I have to use a try-catch for every case ..

```
    case list:
        try{..
        }catch(Exception ex);{
        String error=ex;
        request.setAttribute("error",error);
        link="Error.jsp";
    }
```

..or do I have to use a single try-catch as the first example? (or both?)

Do I have to create a single error.jsp or more then one ?

Is it right to handle exception in the "doGet" method of the servlet?

Comment: what type of exceptions are you expecting that your code will throw. why not configure that in your web.xml with the exceptions tag. upload your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should handle request and response, Don't pass request/response objects to Dao layer.
put your business login into service layer and Dao layer for database interaction.
throw exception from Dao to service and service to controller.
controller will catch your exception will decide what should return in response.
use custom error pages by defining in WEB-INF/web.xml.